# Error using mssql+pyodbc via sqlalchemy to connect to MS SQL Server from Linux

Tags: python, sql-server, freetds

I have a Python application that runs on a Linux machine and connects to an MS SQL Server database running in a Windows Server inside a virtual machine.  I have my reasons.  My application makes some large queries and processes a lot of data.  It mostly works fine, but every so often the program just crashes with the following:

> python: read.c:207: tds_get_string: Assertion `dest_size >= (size_t)
> string_len' failed.

I'm not sure where to start with this.  There is no Python stack trace.  Rather, the program just prints the above and terminates.  If this were a normal exception I could catch it and deal with it.

My sqlalchemy connection string is:

> mssql+pyodbc://username:password@localhost:1433/database?driver=FreeTDS

If it's important, tsql -C gives the following output:

> Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
>
> ```
>                         Version: freetds v0.91
>          freetds.conf directory: /etc/freetds
>  MS db-lib source compatibility: no
>     Sybase binary compatibility: yes
>                   Thread safety: yes
>                   iconv library: yes
>                     TDS version: 4.2
>                           iODBC: no
>                        unixodbc: yes
>           SSPI "trusted" logins: no
>                        Kerberos: yes
> ```

My guess is that my problem is the result of a bug in freetds.  I installed freetds and unixodbc through apt-get on my Linux Mint machine.   I installed pyodbc via pip, and I'm using anaconda.  I've been experimenting with installing various different versions of freetds, unixodbc, and pyodbc from source.  So far, I haven't found a combination that works at all.  However, I don't really know what I'm doing.  I'm looking for explanations, ideas, or workarounds.  Or, of course, simple and complete solutions.

Comment: Can you include your connection string? What TDS Version are you using? Also, for more comprehensive FreeTDS stack traces, you can turn on error logging to a dump file: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/logging.htm These should provide some clues.

Comment: @FlipperPA Thanks for the link.  I think the TDS version is in the tsql -C output?  I will add my connection string to my question.

Answer (score 10):

I found a workaround: don't use freetds.  It turns out there is a microsoft odbc driver available for linux.  I followed the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568454(v=sql.110).aspx) to install it.  I had to upgrade my kernel, among other things, to make it work.  Once installed, I looked in my odbcinst.ini file and there was a new entry, "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server".  I changed my sqlalchemy connections string to match it:

> mssql+pyodbc://username:password@localhost:1433/database?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server

and now everything seems to be working.  The microsoft driver feels significantly slower than freetds (I haven't actually timed it), but I'm not experiencing any of the errors I was before.

Comment: That solution will work; I've had issues with the MS ODBC driver in the past, but haven't tried the most recent versions. Older versions had issues with any code that used threading (like Django's `manage.py runserver`). With FreeTDS, the TDS Version from `tsql -C` is just the global default version. If you choose to go back to FreeTDS, you'll have to include a `TDS_Version=7.x` in your connection string.